# Extended syntax support for R--and R runner--inside of Cloud9 IDE

Tags: r, language-server-protocol, cloud9

I have installed R into AWS Cloud9 Via Bash with the following script:

```
mkdir R
cd R
wget http://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-3/R-3.0.3.tar.gz
tar -xzf R-3.0.3.tar.gz
rm R-3.0.3.tar.gz
cd R-3.0.3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install r-base
someone:~/workspace/R-3.0.3 $ R
```

How would I go about building a runner that runs .R files, and how to get further syntax support, with things like a Language Server? I need at *least* a tutorial video for doing this, since I do not really understand how to set up something along the lines of this.

I have installed R, **and that is about it.**

 I am just asking the community for something
like a guide.

Comment: Hi chrom, welcome to SO. While it's appreciated that it can be challenging to find solutions when you are starting out, your question is considered off-topic for this site. SO is for debugging existing code and programming issues. [This link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251134/2530121) may offer some suggestions to get you started. However, there are specific rules regarding questions for all Stack Exchange sites so be sure to check before posting. Good luck!